# Regex para validar número de documento nacional

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando criar um validador de documentos nacionais que aceite números e letras ou somente número com limite de 11 caracteres em JavaScript.

O problema está na criação do regex.

Segue o código:

```
var documento = 'abc123-$/';
alert(documento.replace(/^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,5}\d+[A-Za-z0-9]{0,6}$g/,"")); // resultado deveria ser: abc123

var documento = 'abcdef-$/';
alert(documento.replace(/^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,5}\d+[A-Za-z0-9]{0,6}$g/,"")); // resultado deveria ser vazio porque deve conter pelo menos 1 número
```

Segue um exemplo no JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L84c91nb/)

Comment: No caso de documentos, acho que seria melhor fazer o [cálculo do(s) dígito(s) verificador(es)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADgito_verificador), que eles geralmente possuem (descubra qual é o cálculo do documento que vc está trabalhando e implemente-o). Apesar da regex "funcionar", nem toda sequência de 11 dígitos/letras será um documento válido, caso este possua dígitos verificadores - e neste caso o cálculo destes já garante que o número do documento é válido, tornando a regex desnecessária.

Comment: Isso é meio impossivel porque estou usando um campo para todos os documentos nacionais. É um sistema de venda de passagens online, é necessário somente que o usuário preencha um documento com foto, pode ser desde carteira de trabalho a carteirinha da AOB num mesmo campo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize esta expressão regular: `(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,11}`

Em que a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5yCLt8/1) pode ser vista.

#### Explicação

- `(?=.*\d)` - Positive Lookahead, em que garante que pelo menos um número está presente na string.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,11}` - Corresponde de 1 a 11 caracteres de `A` a `Z` ou de `a` a `z` ou de `0` a `9`. Então não são permitidos caracteres especiais.

#### Outro caso

Caso seja somente números ou letras de 1 a 11 caracteres, utilizar a seguinte expressão regular: `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,11}`

Sem a parte de verificar se há pelo menos um dígito.