# Regex para validar documento - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tendo alguns problemas na hora de validar o documento.

Anteriormente eu fiz essa pergunta aqui: [Regex para validar número de documento nacional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336951/regex-para-validar-n%c3%bamero-de-documento-nacional)

O problema que estou tendo é que o usuário está digitando números sequeciais ou iguais, por exemplo:

- 000000000
- 111111111

até

- 999999999

e também coisas do tipo:

- 1234567890
- 0987654321
- 123123123
- 456456456
- abc123

e isso está me dando um problemão. Preciso que, a regex, valide números e letras, ou somente números, sem ser sequencial, sem ser iguais, sem existir 'abc' ou coisas do genero, sem existir caracteres especiais, sem espaços. Um exemplo de validação correta e incorreta:

- 90956780083 - true
- PR213328112 - true
- 00000000000 - false
- 0000 - false
- 123456789 - false
- 1234 - false
- abc123 - false
- 456456 - false
- 987654321 - false
- 3210 - false
- çá058 - false
- PR 213328112 - false
- PR.213328112 - false

Bom, segue a regex que tenho:

```js
console.log(/(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}/g.test('abc1234')); // somente números e letras ou somente números
 console.log(/(?!(\d)\1{3})\d{1,}/g.test('11111')); // numeros iguais (deveria ser false mas retorna true)
// falta o regex para números sequencias e letras sequeciais que não entendi como funciona.
```

Comment: Qual é o seu problemão, não ficou claro para mim. Não quer que apareçam dígitos iguais? Têm de ser todos diferentes?

Comment: Editei a perguntar, acho que agora ficou um pouco mais claro

Comment: ^(\d)\1{2,10} para dar match a números repetidos pode usar isto.

Comment: Em vez de `{1,}`, você pode usar `+`, que é a mesma coisa (uma ou mais ocorrências). E a parte de verificar números sequenciais eu acho mais fácil fazer um loop. Com regex até é possível, mas [não acho que vale a pena a complicação](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3171671).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhcXnM/1) do Regex101:

[image: Regex101]

Com os exemplos dados a seguinte expressão regular pode ser utilizada: `^(?!(\d)\1{10,})(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{11}`

Você já estava tentando utilizar o Negative Lookahead `?!` para resolver este problema, porém em duas expressões diferentes e da maneira incorreta. É possível resolver isto somente com uma expressão.

Com a utilização do `\1` que corresponde à strings repetidas do primeiro grupo de captura `(\d)`, e o quantificador `{10,}` de número de repetições maior do que 10.

E o quantificador da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336951/regex-para-validar-n%c3%bamero-de-documento-nacional) que é `{1,11}`, ou seja, de 1 a 11 caracteres, deve ser mudado para `{11}`, somente 11 caracteres.

Já na parte de números sequenciais, como o @hkotsubo falou, não é necessário expressão regular para isso... Mas você pode criar algo para verificar a presença de `123456789` ou outro negative lookahead

Comment: Muito obrigado! Fiz algumas alterações e ficou ótimo!